# Clearing local storage, site data, and cookies in IE, Chrome, and Firefox for Protractor tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, session-cookies

Is there a way to clear out the site's data, cookies, sessions, etc. in Chrome, Firefox, and IE prior to launching a test using Protractor/Jasmine/Selenium?

I found that if you use something like:

```js
    browser.driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('Got cookies %j', cookies);
        //cookies.deleteCookies(); //correct method?
    });
```

Within the `onPrepare()` it almost did what I wanted it to do, but I wasn't fully able to tell if it was working, and during IE the object came back as an emptyset '[]'.

Is there a better, or more complete, way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```js
browser.get("URL");
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Not sure if exist something better. I found a big problem with that it is that you can not clear all the cookies. It is only available to clear all cookies from one location/url.

Answer (score 0):

After you

`browser.get("url")`

to your page, you can execute JavaScript in it from webdriver:

```js
browser.execute_script('<JS snippet>')
```

e.g.: `'localStorage.clear();'`